# Expo / React-native change fonts between Android and IOS

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to know how to have different fonts for IOS and Android,
I have only 1 index file.(App.js)

My code that works on IOS:

```
<Text style={{fontFamily: 'AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin'}}>Hello!</Text>
```

But when I open the App on Android I see the standard font (Arial?)

I tried something like this:

```
<Text style={{fontFamily:'Roboto', fontFamily:'AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin'>Hello!</Text>
```

But this just gives me an Error that the font wasn't found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use condition in your style using Platform component from React Native

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native';

<Text style={{fontFamily: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 'AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin' : 'Roboto'}}>Hello!</Text>
```

Also be sure fonts are well imported.

Otherwise import them with the following steps.

1 - Place the fonts you want to use in a directory inside your project. For example in ./assets/fonts/

2 - Add the following line in your package.json:

```
“rnpm”: {
   “assets”: [“./assets/fonts”]
}
```

3 - run in terminal:

```
$ react-native link
```